# Validation function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Objective note : html cannot be change~

1. Initiating the validation function
2. AccessCode form field must be filled in. if not display alter message "please enter a valid access code"
3. AccessCode: Consists of 3 digits followed by an exclamation mark, as in 555! Use regular expression. if not properly entered, display the alert message "Enter the valid code"

This is what I've done so far, and it not working since the submit input type by default is button type and not submit type.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate() 
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["accessCode"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
 alert("please enter and Access Code");
 return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name ="myForm" id="theForm" method="get" action="formprocessor.html">
<p id="a">Enter Access Code
<input type="text" id="accessCode" name="accessCode" value="" /> </p>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Validate" /> </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are calling your function?

Comment: thank you for replying! I tried to add <input type="button" id="submit" value="Validate" onclick="return Validate()"/> </p> and it work! now all I need is to know how to add regular expression

Answer (score 0):

For regular expression try following code.

```
function Validate() 
{
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["accessCode"].value;
  var re=/^([0-9]{1,3})+[\!]$/;
  if (x==null || x=="")
  {
    alert("please enter and Access Code");
    return false;
  }
  else if(x.length == 4)
  {
    if(!x.match(re))
    {
      alert("Enter the valid code. e.g 555!");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;    
    }
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Enter the valid code. e.g 555!");
    return false;
  }
}
```